# Cycles in $S_n$ form a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

For which  $n,n\ge2$ , do the cycles in $S_n$  form a subgroup?

I am not getting the right way to approach the solution.

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Have you worked out the answer for $n = 2$, $3$ and $4$? (Remember to count the identity as a cycle or the answer is trivial.)

Comment: I am not exactly getting the question,if I take all the cycles then its the group itself?I may not be right.I have just started learning group theory.

Comment: If you start with all the cycles and then close under multiplication (function composition), which permutations can you reach?

Comment: the permutations in S_n precisely.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that by a cycle you mean an element consisting of a single cycle, like $(135)$ for example, but not $(12)(34)$.

Anyway for $n \ge 4$ it's easy to notice that $(12)(34)$ isn't a element of the subgroup, as it consists of two disjoint cycles. Therefore for $n \ge 4$ cycles don't constitute a subgroup, as it's not closed under the operation.

For $n=2,3$ it's fairly easy to notice that the set of cycles is actually $S_2$ and $S_3$, which is a group, although nontrivial.

Comment: I'd hoped my hint in a comment would have helped the OP answer the question him/herself.